# Laravel - Conversion of my Plain PHP Code to Laravel (Controller and View)

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on Payment integration.

[image: Payment]

This is my model class

Model: PayData:

```
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'key',
        'email',
        'amount',
        'ref',
        'mobileNumber'
        ];
}
```

I have some plain PHP Code I want to convert into Laravel. I want to create controller and view with the plain PHP Code:

Plain PHP Code below:

```html
The form is shown below:

<form>
  <script src="https://js.stack.co/v1/inline.js"></script>
  <button type="button" onclick="payWithStack()"> Pay </button> 
</form>
```

payWithStack function

```html
<!-- place below the html form -->
<script>
  function payWithStack(){
    var handler = PaystackPop.setup({
      key: 'paste your key here',
      email: 'customer@email.com',
      amount: 10000,
      ref: ''+Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1), // generates a pseudo-unique reference. Please replace with a reference you generated. Or remove the line entirely so our API will generate one for you
      metadata: {
         custom_fields: [
            {
                display_name: "Mobile Number",
                variable_name: "mobile_number",
                value: "+2348012345678"
            }
         ]
      },
      callback: function(response){
          alert('success. transaction ref is ' + response.reference);
      },
      onClose: function(){
          alert('window closed');
      }
    });
    handler.openIframe();
  }
</script>
```

initialize.php

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

$email = "your@email.com";
$amount = 30000;  //the amount in kobo. This value is actually NGN 300

// url to go to after payment
$callback_url = 'myapp.com/pay/callback.php';  

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
 'amount'=>$amount,
 'email'=>$email,
 'callback_url' => $callback_url
  ]),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
  "authorization: Bearer sk_test_36658e3260b1d1668b563e6d8268e46ad6da3273", 
//replace this with your own test key
"content-type: application/json",
"cache-control: no-cache"
],
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

if($err){
// there was an error contacting the Paystack API
die('Curl returned error: ' . $err);
}

$tranx = json_decode($response, true);

if(!$tranx->status){
 // there was an error from the API
  print_r('API returned error: ' . $tranx['message']);
}

// comment out this line if you want to redirect the user to the payment page
print_r($tranx);
  // redirect to page so User can pay
  // uncomment this line to allow the user redirect to the payment page
  header('Location: ' . $tranx['data']['authorization_url']);
```

callback.php

```html
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
$reference = isset($_GET['reference']) ? $_GET['reference'] : '';
if(!$reference){
  die('No reference supplied');
}

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/" . rawurlencode($reference),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "accept: application/json",
    "authorization: Bearer sk_test_36658e3260b1d1668b563e6d8268e46ad6da3273",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ],
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

if($err){
    // there was an error contacting the Paystack API
  die('Curl returned error: ' . $err);
}

$tranx = json_decode($response);

if(!$tranx->status){
  // there was an error from the API
  die('API returned error: ' . $tranx->message);
}

if('success' == $tranx->data->status){
  // transaction was successful...
  // please check other things like whether you already gave value for this ref
  // if the email matches the customer who owns the product etc
  // Give value
  echo "<h2>Thank you for making a purchase. Your file has bee sent your email.</h2>"
}
```

How do I achieve these plain PHP  code to Laravel

Comment: maybe you oughta know laravel first, that seems better in the long run

Comment: thats well broken down. moreso, you need to do some home work!

Answer (score 0):

Oke first: Take your time to learn and understand the Laravel framework.

Laravel is a PHP framework, this means that you don't really convert plain PHP into Laravel PHP. Any plain PHP will work in Laravel, but things sometimes have to be in a certain structure or order.

My suggestion is to start by setting up a laravel project, follow some tutorials on Laracast and watch a few youtube videos about the structure of laravel.

Then:

1. Make a new view for the form and javascript in the resources folder.(or make a reference to the js file inside the view)
2. Make a controller in the app/http/controllers folder. All your code from initialize.php can go in a function that you can name initalize() and the code from callback.php in a function that you could name callback().
3. Make at least 2 routes in the routes/web.php file 1 for the initialize function and one for the callback function.
4. Not sure how stack works, but I think you can add the 2 routes or at least the callback route to the stack(or other payment provider) config.

I hope this helps to get started.

Have fun learning/coding/creating!

Answer (score 0):

function getJogosByHorario()
{
$query = "SELECT *, cd.Tipo as TipoCidade, jg.id as id_jogo  FROM `bichojogo` jg
INNER JOIN usuarios bc ON bc.id = jg.idBanca
INNER JOIN cidades cd ON bc.cidadetitle = cd.title
WHERE `bichohorario` = :Horario
AND cast(jg.dataCriacao as DATE ) = :DataJogo
AND jg.Status = '0' AND jg.local = :local
AND lixeira is null";
$prepare = Conn::getConn()->prepare($query);
$prepare->execute(
[
'DataJogo' => inputPost('DataJogo'),
'local' => inputPost('local'),
'Horario' => inputPost('Horario')
]
);

```
return $prepare->fetchAll();
```

}

Comment: Don't paste raw code like this, make some sentences and explain why your anwser should help